# Sphinx and Primary Key Column

Tags: primary-key, sphinx

I am trying to learn about the Sphinx search server. I have it working through the command line and through PHP. The only nagging thing is that when I index a table, Sphinx returns a notice that says it could not find the Primary Key column and 'ignores' that column. It works anyway, so I did not pay that much mind, but now I've noticed that I am getting PHP notices from my search script saying that the primary key column q_id is undefined. The script works and returns the proper q_ids but I do not like getting the notices.

Here is a snippet so you can see where I am trying to get the primary key column.

```
$row_ids = array();
  if ( ! empty($result["matches"]) ) {
      foreach ( $result["matches"] as $doc => $docinfo ) {

   array_push($row_ids, $docinfo['q_id']);
      }
```

I understand that Sphinx does not recognize what a Primary Key is, but I figured it could still index the column, and it must do something with it because searches are returning the correct q_ids. Where am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Actually I just determined that the above code does not give me the q_id, although it knows that there are results to give (ie, if I know there should be five results returned, it gives the undefined variable notice 5 times, if 9 results, then 9 times. If I just print_r the result["matches"] variable, the script will show the ids. It just says that the $doc_info['q_id'] is undefined. Should I be calling those doc ids a different way?

Answer (score 1):

Is "q_id" an attribute?

Would be something like

```
  foreach ( $result["matches"] as $doc => $docinfo ) {
       array_push($row_ids, $docinfo['attrs']['q_id']);
  }
```

You should do a print_r($result); to see everything returned...

Comment: No, I don't think it's an attribute. It is the primary key for the table that is indexed and searched on. I changed the above code to the following which works, but do not understand why Sphinx does not recognize the primary key of the table.                      $row_ids = array();
if ( ! empty($result["matches"]) ) {
     foreach ( $result["matches"] as $doc => $docinfo ) {       
          }
$IDs = implode(",",array_keys($result["matches"]));  
     }

Comment: SPhinx knows nothing about the table. It just runs the query in 'sql_query' and indexes the results. It knows nothing of the indexes on the table.

Comment: Right. So suppose the query run in sql_query is to SELECT each column of a table, the first of which is the primary key column containing integers, those integers don't get indexed as well? I ask because something must be happening to those integers, because those integers are spit out as the results of the search.

Comment: The first column is always the document_id - they are the unique id, used to reference each document. So yes they are stored in the index.